# meteor facebook login and set current user

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I need a help or guide on this:
I am making a facebook app and I wish it to make in meteor.

When user opens my app, it automatically authenticates the user with facebook and pop ups dialogue box. And when user is authenticated or connected to facebook I want to save the user to meteor's user collection and set current user to facebook user.

I am new at meteor and didn't find a head point for this. Hope someone will guide me out.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I think automatic authentication is a bad practice both from UI perspective and from user perspective. If i open something, I want to be able to decide for myself if I want to authenticate a third party application with facebook so I'd have a button that promps people to signup with Facebook. You'll need:

- accounts-password
- accounts-facebook
- service-configuration [more info](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice)

Read through that flow and there is an example of setting a singup event up.